# Trying to decide which page should be my home page

Tags: website-design, design-patterns

I'm not a UI person and would love to get your recommendation -

which page should be my homepage?

1. myvoternation.com

or

1. http://myvoternation.com/mvn/questions

Comment: This is not a real question - rather it is SPAM designed to put up a link to another site.

Comment: @Tim - agree completely.

Comment: Maybe a better phrasing would be:  Which is better UX; making your homepage be the content or having a splash page with information about what it is?  In other words, use foreplay or just dive right in?

Comment: If it truly isn't spam, then, OP: please use example.com

Comment: @Tim Holt Why do you feel this is spam? The question asker commented on an answer below, and they need to link to their site somehow in order for us to see what they're talking about. If there's a reason to close this question, it's because it could use more details, such as context and what is trying to be achieved.

Comment: It's too late now (already closed), but I have to agree with @Rahul: a spammer would have never come back to comment on an answer.

Comment: @Rahul & @Hisham - if it was a real question, why wouldn't he have come back to defend it when Tim made that statement?

Answer (score 5):

This is really easy.  Get [Google Site Optimizer](https://www.google.com/analytics/siteopt/) and try both methods.  No one is going to be able to perfectly predict the results.  However, the results answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "should be my homepage" what do you mean? Do you mean for promotional purposes, for site navigation, or something else?

The reason I ask is that, to some extent, myvoternation.com *is* your home page, by definition. The top-level of a site is usually considered as it's homepage. For that reason i'd advise against 'pretending' that another page is your site's home (e.g. In navigation) since that's likely to confuse.

If the content that's currently on /mvn/questions is more relevant when acting as home page content than the content of the current home page, then that's an argument to change the content of the current home page.

Comment: Exactly, trying to decide whether the content page should be the homepage.  That's the big decision.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: [every page is your home page](http://www.twistimage.com/blog/archives/every-page-is-your-homepage/).

Many visitors to your site will arrive via search engines such as Google. Most of these visitors will not land on your home page. This means you have to [treat every page as your start page and write your content accordingly](http://blendinteractive.com/news/home-page-not-start-page/).

For example, I work on a large website where **fewer than 9% of visitors arrive on the home page**.

The [importance of the home page has been in decline for at least 7 years](http://giraffeforum.com/wordpress/2010/04/18/the-decline-of-the-homepage/). This trend seems likely to continue.

For further information I recommend [Myth #17: The homepage is your most important page](http://uxmyths.com/post/717779908/myth-the-homepage-is-your-most-important-page).